# canonical hostname rule with multiple domains

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have this code

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com\.au$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com.au/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.co\.nz$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.co.nz/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When i run this i get "This webpage has a redirect loop" Seems like NZ redirects to AU for some reason.

UPDATE

This seems to work

```
<rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\S+)\.(co(\.nz)?|com\.au)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```